# PHP timezone discrepancy - America/New_York = CDT?

Tags: php, timezone

How does this make sense?

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
echo date("e"); //output "America/New_York"
echo date("T"); //output "CDT"
```

Is there somewhere that I can set America/New_York = EDT?

Comment: I just copy/pasted your above code and ran it.  It produced EDT. Is it possible your timezone tables are messed up?

Comment: I looked for some bug entries on the PHP bug base and there are 4 or 5 bugs related to the use of the "T" modifier. Make sure you have a recent version (at least +5.1) and retry. Also, just saying, could it have something to do with Daylight Savings Time?

Comment: As a follow up: I am using PHP 5.2.6. I updated PHP timezones by installing timezonedb via pecl (see http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). The output still didn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
    echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
} else {
    echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
}
?>
```